# content-type in requests getting overwritten when Chopper library for flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, header, content-type

I recently started working in flutter and now I want to request some data from a server. I used the **Chopper** library to make my work easy but I wasn't getting the expected response so after investigation I found out that my provided content-type in the header was getting over written somewhere in the chopper library or in lower level classes.

Any help would be appreciated. thank you!

I gave-> **content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded**
it got over written to-> **content-type: application/json**

Comment: show your code, how you have done